# How to import multiple .xls files into SAS?

Tags: sas

I have a folder that contains a number of .xls files. The names of the file could be random. The exact number is unknown. How can I import these datasets to SAS by knowing only the folder's directory? I would have to iterate ... i have done this using Java ... I am curious can SAS do this?

Comment: Definitely can be done.  Start with [this](http://support.sas.com/kb/24/820.html), and then use `call execute` to repeatedly run an import macro on the resulting dataset.  Sorry I'm not providing full code, but I don't want to paste a bunch of stuff that I wrote for my employer.

Comment: do you know the sheet name from each xls file you need?  Assuming the sheet names are the same, this is pretty straightforward as @user2161151 says above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get a list of excel files in the folder (using techniques suggested above), you can put it into a macrovariable and loop through them in a macro assigning them one-by-one to a library:

```
%DO i=1 %TO %SYSFUNC(COUNTW(&list_of_files));
   LIBNAME xlibr EXCEL "&your_folder\%scan(&list_of_files,&i)";

   DATA imported_file_&i;
      SET xlibr.'Sheet1$'n;
   RUN;

%END;
```

If name(s) and number of sheets in each file may vary, then you'll need to add one more, nested, loop to iterate through all sheets of each file. Something like this:

```
%DO i=1 %TO %SYSFUNC(COUNTW(&list_of_files));
   LIBNAME xlibr EXCEL "&your_folder\%scan(&list_of_files,&i)";

   PROC SQL noprint;
     SELECT memname into :sheets separated by ' '
     FROM sashelp.vtable
     WHERE libname="XLIBR";
   QUIT;

   %DO j=1 %TO %SYSFUNC(COUNTW(&sheets));   
      DATA imported_file_&i&j;
         SET xlibr."%scan(&sheets,&j)$"n;
      RUN;
   %END;
%END;
```